# ASP.Net MVC EF - Adding a Child on Parent Create

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC project with a Person class.  The Model, Controller, and basic CRUD Views are established and working.

The project contains a Notes class that allows a one-to-many Person/Notes relationship.  The Notes table stores all of the notes for a variety of entities in the system, so it is related via an EntityGuid.

The Note model is very basic:

```
public class Note {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Guid EntityGuid { get; set; }
        public string NoteBody { get; set; }

}
```

As is the Person Controller's Create method for the POST:

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.Persons.Add(person);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

When creating a person, the Create View has a TinyMCE editor attached to a `textarea` to record the note.  I need the ability to save an initial note (optional) at the time the Person record is saved.  This would be a child record to the Person, linked via EntityGuid to parent.

What is the cleanest/correct way to handle this under code-first ASP.Net MVC EF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the collection of notes defined in your Person class this should do the trick:

```
var note = new Note{NoteBody=noteFromModel};
        if(person.Notes==null)
          person.Notes=new List<Note>();
        person.Notes.Add(note);
    db.Persons.Add(person);
    db.SaveChanges();
```